# phpQuery for current file

Tags: php, domparser, phpquery

I am just trying to get started with phpQuery DOM Parser but I don't understand how to load the current php file so that I can play with elements in this particular page.

Say I have a php file `about.php`. It has a simple markup:

```
<?php
    require('phpQuery/phpQuery.php');
    phpQuery::newDocument();
    pq('div')->addClass('myclass'); // this doesn't work
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>About</title>
    <head>
    <body>
        //Here i have various html elements and i want to play with these elements using PHPQuery.
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: C'mon, at least read the documentation. The "Basics" page at https://code.google.com/p/phpquery/wiki/Basics says you'd do `phpQuery::newDocumentPHP($html, $contentType = null) Read more about it on PHPSupport page`.

Comment: I won't mind getting negative marking.

Comment: i have tried this before posting the question. Here is what i get by doing the way you told
Undefined variable: html in D:\xampp\htdocs\phpQuery\index.php on line 3

Comment: Well, did you load the PHP file's contents into `$html`? You can't just randomly copy/paste others' code without understanding anything about it.

Comment: That is what my question says. How would i get the current file html to $html

Comment: http://php.net/file_get_contents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a strange request, but you could do:

```
$html = file_get_contents(__FILE__);
$dom = phpQuery::newDocument($html);
```